# How replace a word in text file in specific position using Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, replace

```
test_list = ['4', 'kg', 'butter', 'for', '40', 'bucks']
print("The original list : " + str(test_list) )
res = [sub.replace('4', '1') for sub in test_list ]
print("\nThe list after substring replacement : " + str(res))
```

This program works for string. How to do the same type word replacement for a text file ?
input file content:4, kg, butter, for, 40, bucks
expected o/p file content : for,kg, butter,4, 40, bucks

Comment: What is the output you would expecet? what is `fcont`?

Comment: Sorry. Edited..

Comment: Take a look at my answer, i think it answer your question after this edit

Comment: input file content:4, kg, butter, for, 40, bucks*******
ouput: for,kg, butter,4, 40, bucks

Comment: Paste the content of the file into the post, and the expected output

Comment: ok. I have edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the file, replace the values, and dump it again into the file this:

```py
with open('file_path') as f:
    text = f.read()
text.replace('4', '1')
with open('file_path', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

in case its a big file, and you don't want to read it all into the memory aty once you can do it as:

```py
import os
with open('output_file', 'w') as output:
    with open('input_file') as f:
        for line in f.splitlines():
            output.write(line.replace('4', '1'))
os.rename(output_file, input_file)
```